# Connect ASUS R9 280X to Corsair HX850

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

Need to connect an ASUS r9 280x graphics card to Corsair HX850 PSU. There are 6 pin and 8 pin power connectors on the graphics card and 8 pin PCIE power connectors on the PSU. Cables available for connecting are a 6 pin to 6 Pin PCIE cable and a 6 Pin to 6+2 pin PCIE. 8 Pin to 2 x Molex connector cable was supplied with the card but from researching this I have discounted this option as most opinion states this is unsuitable and possibly dangerous. As there are PCIE power connectors on the PSU I would prefer to use these. Have already connected the 6 pin graphics card connector to psu using 6 pin to 6 pin cable.

My question is this can I use the 6 pin to 6+ 2 pin cable to complete the connection from the 8 pin connector on the graphics card to the psu  or do i need a specific 8 pin to 8 pin cable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand this. If what you said is true, you have 6 connectors which are all 6+2 pin PCIE connectors. This is only set up like this to make the PSU more flexible so it can plug into 6 pin or 8 pin PCIE ports. take a 6+2 PCIE connector from the PSU and plug it straight into the card.